# How to solve the TS7009 TypeScript error?

Tags: typescript

I am new in Typescript programming. Now I am in learning phase. I have face a problem during coding through receiving an error in back end console.
The above mentioned code is:

```
function employee(id:number,name:string) { 
   this.id = id 
   this.name = name 
} 

var emp = new employee(123,"Smith") 
employee.prototype.email = "smith@abc.com" 

console.log("Employee 's Id: "+emp.id) 
console.log("Employee's name: "+emp.name) 
console.log("Employee's Email ID: "+emp.email)
```

Output @ Browser console is:

```
www.ts:10 Employee 's Id: 123
www.ts:11 Employee's name: Smith
www.ts:12 Employee's Email ID: smith@abc.com
```

And the error in Node console is:

```
[0] www/www.ts(6,15): error TS7009: 'new' expression, whose target lacks
a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Please help me to resolve this error.
Thanks....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In TypeScript you should use `new` only on classes. Consider rewriting it like so:

```
class Employee {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;

    constructor(id:number, name:string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

let emp = new Employee(123,"Smith");
emp.email = "smith@abc.com";
```

I don't understand what you were trying to achieve with the prototype property assignment.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change your existing code, you can use:

```
new (employee as any)(123, "smith")
```